# Return an object dynamically from a method that accepts only type of class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am working on .NET framework 3.5 
I have a requirement to create a method in C#, which can accept one of the 5 types of classes and generate object dynamically using the class type that I pass to the method. So basically there are 2 inputs to this method. One is type of class, and another is the data object that I need to fill the object with. 
Once the method is invoked, it should automatically create an object of the type of class that I sent , and fill the fields with the data object that I sent.
I tried using System.reflection's createinstance, and got an object with desired class, however, I am struck at a point where I have to populate the fields with the data object that I have. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Edit : `public class DataInput
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    public string field4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime field5 { get; set; }
    public DateTime field6 { get; set; }


}
My 5 classes look like this :

public class Class1
{
    public string field1;
    public string field2;
    public string field3;
    public string field4;
    public DateTime field5;
}

public class Class2
{
    public string field1;
    public string field2;
    public string field3;

}

public class Class3
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;
    public string field3;

}

public class Class4
{
    public int field1;
    public string field2;
    public string field3;
    public DateTime field4;


}
public class Class5
{
    public int field1;
    public DateTime field2;
    public string field3;

}

public void Convert(DataInput ratCommon, Type type1)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(type1.AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString());
    if (type != null)
    {
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);  //This  creates an instance with type I passed, but I am struck here

    }
}
I combined @Fabjan answer and @striplingwarrior answer and got the result. I can't thank you enough....
```

Comment: Please provide us some code, so we can take a look whats going on

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you out, we'll need to know more about the kind of data you're dealing with. If the data is in a standard format there's a good chance you can find a library that'll do this for you. For JSON, it could be as simple as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, type)`. Otherwise you'll probably need to parse the data in some way and use reflection to set field or property values on the object. Go ahead and edit your answer to add information rather than using comments.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620828/factory-to-create-different-objects-of-same-interface/39620931#39620931

Comment: I have edited the question with code......

Comment: @StriplingWarrior It's standard format, not JSON. Can I ask you for the library that you are referring to , pls ?

Comment: @Fabjan I am trying this...will get back to you with results

Comment: Thank you @Fabjan I am not sure how I can mark your comment as answer

Comment: @CRS Well, you can't but I'm glad that it is working for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Start by initializing mappings between your classes.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<DataInput, Class1>();
    cfg.CreateMap<DataInput, Class2>();
    // etc.
});
```

Note: You may need to create some custom mappings [like projections](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Projection.html), because it looks like the types of your fields don't always match up.

Then you can leverage the Mapper.Map methods:

```
public object Convert(DataInput ratCommon, Type type1) => Mapper.Map(foo, typeof(DataInput), type1);
```

Or, if `type1` is known at compile-time, you can get type safety via generics:

```
public T Convert<T>(DataInput ratCommon) => Mapper.Map<T>(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am struck at a point where I have to populate the fields with the data object that I have.

That's because the compiler has no idea what type is being returned, so it can't bind to the properties of the *runtime* type.

Depending on how you're getting the data for the runtime object, you have some options:

- Reflection - find properties with the names you want to set using reflectrion
- `dynamic` - use `dynamic` to defer all prpoerty binding until runtime (basically the same as above but letting the compiler generate the necessary reflection code)
- Deserialization - use existing libraries to deserialize from XML, JSON, etc.

Comment: •Deserialization - use existing libraries to deserialize from XML, JSON, etc   >>>> I am not getting the data in XML, JSON format, but I am curious to know what are the libraries you are referring to ...?