# c# generic method that create class with construct or with obj parameters

Tags: c#

I don't if is possible create something like that:

```
async static Task method<T>(object obj = null) where T : SomeClass, new()
{
    SomeClass s;
    if (obj != null)
        s = new T(obj);
    else
        s = new T();
}
```

I want to create a class in my method with default construct but sometimes it need an object given.

Update :

```
class A : SomeClass
{
    public A() {
        ...
    }
}

class B : SommeClass
{
    public B(Object obj)
    {
        ... //using obj
    }

}
```

Comment: No you can't do this, you would need to use `Activator.CreateInstance`, however, this does look like a code smell to me. Probably better to use a factory of some sort.

Comment: Why marking as `async`?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620828/factory-to-create-different-objects-of-same-interface/39620931#39620931

Comment: As written, it's unclear what utility calling this method would have. How is `method<Something>()` or `method<Something>(other)` better than `new Something()` or `new Something(other)`?

Comment: could you post the 2 constructors of `SomeClass` ? may be you should actually start there to change, so that construct you posted becomes resolved

Comment: i create my class in my generic method because a have a loading UI and create my class before calling my generic method may create a delay between User event and the display of the loading.

Comment: @coco I've read your comment several times.  It does not make sense.  What delay are you talking about?  This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: More flexible than a `new()` constraint is to use a `Func<T>` delegate being passed in that produces the object however it wants -- this can capture parameters as well.

Comment: I'm working in mobile App, and I have a button that switching view to the new one when the user click on it but if I create my new view before displaying my loader that may create a delay between the time he click and the time the display showing, in constructor of the view can have multiple thing. Sorry for my bad English.